# Chrome extension sendRequest from async callback not working?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Can't figure out what's wrong. onRequest not triggered on call from async callback method, the same request from content script works. The sample code below.

```
background.js
=============
...
makeAsyncRequest();
...
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  switch (request.id) {
    case "from_content_script":
      // This works
      console.log("from_content_script");
      sendResponse({}); // clean up
    break;
    case "from_async":
      // Not working!
      console.log("from_async");
      sendResponse({}); // clean up
    break;
  }
});

methods.js
==========
makeAsyncRequest = function() {
  ...
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      ...
      // It works
      console.log("makeAsyncRequest callback");
      chrome.extension.sendRequest({id: "from_async"}, function(response) {  });
    }
  }
  ...
};
```

**UPDATE:** manifest configuration file. Don't no what's wrong here.

```
{
  "name": "TestExt",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "icons": {
    "48": "img/icon-48-green.gif"
  },
  "description": "write it later",
  "background_page": "background.html",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "TestExt",
    "default_icon": "img/icon-48-green.gif"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file://*/*",
    "webNavigation"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where is `methods.js` placed? Can you show all of your code, including `manifest.json`?

Comment: The `manifest.json` is added, but you still haven't shown how `methods.js` is executed. Where is it located? Can you expand the `...`?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think the problem is your sending the message from async request but because your trying to send a message from the same page the receiver is on?  You can put that sendmessage out of the onreadystatechange but still in the background page and it still wont fire.  Why would you want to send a message to the same page anywayz?

I just put your xhr request in a content script and it called just fine, so now Im sure its because your sending the message from the same page the receiver is on.

Comment: I'm using `bgpage.processAsyncResults()` in 'methods.js' now. But I think it's wrong design approach.

Comment: Okay, I think I should pass backgr callback func reference to makeAsyncRequest - seems the right solution.